# PhpStorm Xdebug, WSL2, Docker // Cannot evaluate expression '$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']'

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running a Magento2 PHP app inside a set of docker containers that are orchestrated by docker-compose locally. I'm running Docker Desktop for Windows in WSL2 mode.

My php 7.3 interpreter with Xdebug sits inside one of those containers. Once I'm in FPM context - I can debug things fine if I just have activated remote debugging in PhpStorm.

Now I need to debug a CLI script and PhpStorm shows me following error:

```
Cannot evaluate expression '$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']'
```

So Xdebug can clearly reach PhpStorm, all tips that I found on this JetBrains support forums, StackOverflow or otherwise on Google doesn't seem to solve the problem. I think `SERVER_PORT` is generally not available when we are running things in CLI context.

Also I can't setup CLI interpreter in PhpStorm properly:

- SSH - I don't have ssh server, and adding it to the container just for PhpStorm debugging sounds like an overkill
- Docker - I need to connect to a running container and not start a new one from the image (I need persistent database connection for that script), also the actual image that is supposed to be executed locally is a multi-stage image, PhpStorm doesn't support that.
- Docker Compose - doesn't work, I don't have docker compose on Windows, everything is inside WSL "containers"
- WSL - doesn't work, my php is not inside WSL, it is one level deeper - inside Docker that runs under WSL.

```
PHP 7.3.18-1+0~20200515.59+debian10~1.gbp12fa4f (cli) (built: May 15 2020 12:43:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.18, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.18-1+0~20200515.59+debian10~1.gbp12fa4f, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.9.6, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

This Xdebug config works for debugging in FPM context:

```
cat xdebug.ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
; this is IP of windows host that is visible for docker
xdebug.remote_host=172.31.64.1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

How can I get Xdebug to also work in CLI context?

Comment: How do you start a CLI script if you do not have SSH access already?

Comment: 1) Yes, PHP does not populate `$_SERVER` in CLI context. 2) For remote CLI you need to specify this: `export PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=SomeName"` where "SomeName" is the name of your `PHP | Servers` entry (path mappings etc). This should work for any remote CLI (original ticket: [WI-7906](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-7906)). IDE should not looks for a port/server name in $_SERVER then. P.S. I have not checked CLI debug in WSL or Docker myself, but it works like that just fine in ordinary virtual (VMware Workstation powered image)

Comment: @GhostGambler you don't need SSH to access docker container, communication to the script/TTY goes via docker daemon as far as I know.

Comment: @LazyOne your advice actually worked, do you want to post an answer?